# Finder file dialogue very restricted - any way to enhance it?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

I am referring to a finder dialogue which opens e.g. when you chose to open / save a file in another application.

The context menu items that finder exposes are quite limited (you cannot open a file, etc.) compared to the regular finder.

[image]

This is kind of a silly restriction that I cannot see on any other OS. One of my regular workflows is to open a file from one of the dialogues, copy another file into it, etc.

Any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Why don't you just open a Finder window for such manipulations?

Comment: It's an extra step that takes time? Opening finder, navigating to the exact path, etc. Seems like in MacOS everything is designed to make you slow and take your time...

Comment: It's easier to get fact-based and helpful answers if you ask for what you want and need (and not so much what you miss). Also, more often than not, things you dislike might be things other like, so to avoid heated discussions please focus facts instead of judgement.

Comment: Sorry, frustration got the better of me. I was looking for way to expose all context menu items of the normal finder in the file picker. Maybe that sums it up better.

Comment: I sometimes run into the restrictions on save dialog.  It's frustration. I think the restrictions are there to simplify the UI to focus on what is needed to save a file. This is what you said you would be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicate in comments that you need a free solution.

There's no free solution to do what you want currently. macOS does not come with a preference settings that enhanced that specific context menu.

If you're able to program yourself, it should be possible to add extra menu items to the menu. This should be possible free of cost, but will ofcourse take time.

As others have recommend, there's commercial solution such as "[Default Folder X](https://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html)" available.

In your comments you also express that you find not only the file picker dialog, but also the standard Finder to be very limiting for you. In this case, you could consider using an alternative to Finder.

Some good examples of alternatives are "[Path Finder 9](https://cocoatech.com/)" and "[Commander One](https://mac.eltima.com/file-manager.html)". The first costs a bit, while the latter is free in the standard version.